# EventEmitter calls the handler even after removing it

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, eventemitter

I have two classes named say `A` and `B` both has two methods named `start` and `done`. I create instance of both the classes.

```
var a = new A();
var b = new B();
```

I bind `start` event on `b` and `done` event to `a`.

`a` emits `start` so `b.start` is called, and `b` emits `done` so `a.done` is called. and this process continues until `a.done` decides and stops emitting `start`. It works fine till there is only one instance of `B`.

When I create two instances of `B`. `b.start` fires one extra time than it should.

and interestingly, when I emit `done` within a `setTimeout()` of zero ms, it works perfectly fine.

I am not sure if I explained it correctly. Please suggest what could be the cause. I tried lots of stuff which didn't give me a reason as why adding `setTimeout` helps.

Comment: JSFiddle? I suspect this will trace back to how you've implemented `start` and `done` ... but there's no code to look at

Comment: I will try and make a sample on fiddle. I just wanted to see if its a known problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an EventEmitter listen to another EventEmitter in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26465358/how-to-make-an-eventemitter-listen-to-another-eventemitter-in-node-js)